# SQL Create View with sum and 2 tables

Tags: sql, view

I have following tables:

Project:

```
ProjID Projekt
11     A
12     B
13     C
```

personal

```
PID Person
1   Hans
2   Rolf
3   Ursula
4   Paul
```

projectzugehoerigkeit

```
PID ProjID  ProjZeit
1     11    60
1     12    40
2     13    100
3     11    20
3     12    50
3     13    30
4     11    80
4     13    20
```

I am trying to create a VIEW that displays me Projekt from the Project table with the sum of the ProjZeit from projectzugehoerigkeit.

It should look like this:

```
Projekt ProjektStundenInsgesamt
A       160
B       90
C       150
```

I tried it with this:

```
CREATE VIEW ueberblick1 AS 

SELECT project.Projekt, SUM(projektzugehoerigkeit.ProjZeit) AS ProjektStundenInsgesamt 
FROM project, projektzugehoerigkeit 
GROUP BY project.Projekt;
```

but it always looks like this:

```
Projekt ProjektStundenInsgesamt
A       400
B       400
C       400
```

Thank you

Comment: You have a cartesian product by not joining the tables correctly, see [Bad habbits to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the correct way to do a join

```
SELECT project.Projekt, SUM(projektzugehoerigkeit.ProjZeit) AS ProjektStundenInsgesamt 
FROM project, projektzugehoerigkeit 
GROUP BY project.Projekt;
```

does a cross join between project and projektzugehoerigkeit

You need a real join like this

```
SELECT project.Projekt, SUM(projektzugehoerigkeit.ProjZeit) AS ProjektStundenInsgesamt 
FROM project
JOIN projektzugehoerigkeit on project.projid = projektzugehoerigkeit.projid
GROUP BY project.Projekt;
```